# Flutter_local_notification plugin scheduled notification limit

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm developing a reminder mobile app and it notifies using push notifications I used the flutter_local_notifications plugin
But now I realize that it has a limit when it comes to scheduled notifications.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Because I need to schedule hundreds of notifications according to the reminders users create?